# Setup application to use Microsoft accounts with hybridauth

Tags: hybridauth, accounts

I want to set my app's redirect URL to "http://www.mydomain.com/hybridauth/endpoint?hauth.done=Live", in  Microsoft account Developer Center it tells me that

"You must enter a valid domain that begins with http:// or https:// - query strings are not allowed. Length is limited to 248 characters."

the login button redirects to the following url

https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=invalid_request&error_description=The%20provided%20value%20for%20the%20input%20parameter%20%27redirect_uri%27%20is%20not%20valid.%20The%20expected%20value%20is%20%27https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf%27%20or%20a%20URL%20which%20matches%20the%20redirect%20URI%20registered%20for%20this%20client%20application.

Any way I could link to that URL?

Comment: Hi
did you manage to get hybridauth to work with Windows Live?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in the Live provider implementation.

You must edit the hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Live.php file and change the line below:

$this->api->authorize_url = 'https://oauth.live.com/authorize';